# How to turn off bash's "readline arguments" for character repetition?

Tags: bash, shell, iterm2

In a bash shell, [you can type `M-<number> <key>`, where `M` is the meta key, in order to repeat that `<key>` press `<number>` times](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Arguments.html). For example, typing `M-6 a` puts `aaaaaa` on your command line.

On my computer, meta is mapped to the Esc key. That means that a keystroke of `Esc` then `6` is interpreted as `M-6`, and makes the terminal expect another character to repeat:

```
(arg: 6)
```

This is problematic in my case. I use iTerm2 on macOS, and it has a wonderful little feature where it pops up an autocomplete window when you start typing a command with your previous command history. For example, if you use Mercurial and type `hg update`, it lets you select from all the previous bookmarks and commit hashes you've updated to in the past, sorted by most frequent.

The problem comes when I use Esc to dismiss this window. For example, if I start typing `hg update` , and then the autocomplete window comes up, and then I *accidentally* hit escape more than once, and then paste in a commit hash like `6dd0e54`, what I actually end up with in the command line is this:

```
$ hg update ddddddd0e54
```

Why? Because the first Esc key press dismisses the autocomplete window, the second starts the `M-` key combination, and then the `6d` in the pasted hash is interpreted as "repeat the `d` character `6` times."

This is infuriating, especially when dealing with more problematic commit hashes like `787075d`: in this case it will *literally* put nearly 800 thousand `d` characters into my terminal, rendering it unusable.

So knowing that I never use these readline repetition arguments except by accident, is there any way of turning this feature off, ideally in bash but alternatively in iTerm2?

Comment: there is an answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/770827/how-to-disable-alt-numkey-in-bash-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running

```
bind -p | grep '"\\e1"'
```

returns

```
"\e1": digit-argument
```

So, just remove all the bindings to `digit-argument` by `bind -r`:

```
for i in - {0..9} ; do
    bind -r '\e'$i
done
```

`-` is bound to `digit-argument`, too, to allow for negative arguments.

Comment: Thanks. This does answer the question as asked.

Unfortunately, this leads to a situation where a commit hash of `6dd0e54` is pasted as `dd0e54`, stripping the first character, which is better but still not super-great. I'm going to go hunting for a way to turn off Esc-as-Meta in iTerm2, but that's a bit outside the scope of what I asked for, so I'll accept this answer.